# Isomorphism of quotient groups: if $G_1 \cong G_2$, then $G_1/K_1 \cong G_2/K_2$?

Tags: group-isomorphism, free-groups, quotient-group

Well, I have a little doubt. If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are free groups in $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively. If we have $\langle x^2 : x \in G_1 \rangle = K_1 \lhd G_1$ and $\langle y^2 : y \in G_2 \rangle = K_2 \lhd G_2$. We can conclude that: if $G_1 \cong G_2$, then $G_1/K_1 \cong G_2/K_2$? If so, could you give me any tips on where to start?

Comment: You name $H_1$ and $H_2$ but they don't appear in your question so what is their significance? And there are no hypotheses relating $K_1$ and $K_2$; as written, take $G_1 = G_2, K_1 = \{ e \}, K_2 = G_2$.

Comment: So what I wrote is false, isn't it?

Comment: Your new question is completely different from your old question and much more specific. Now the statement is true. If $\phi : G_1 \to G_2$ is any isomorphism, show that $\phi(K_1) = K_2$, which gives your desired result. The special property of this subgroup that you've defined is that it is *characteristic*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup

Comment: Can you help me understand the Qiaochu process?